# Is it possible to run Meterpreter command in background

Tags: metasploit, meterpreter

After spawning a meterpreter session from the target Windows 7 system I wanted to search for all the files with sub-string "clue" in in their name. As `search -f "*clue*"` took a long time to complete, I found it a waste of time. I want to know if it's possible to make it a background task somehow and get the meterpreter prompt back?

I tried my luck with Google but it only shows results for Meterpreter's `background` command which sends the entire session to background and gives us the msf prompt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are three ideas to consider:

- Use bgrun with search_dwld.rb
- Use file_collector.rb
- Create your own script

---

## bgrun

The best solution I can find for this is to use the command `bgrun`. As the [Metasploit script](https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/blob/master/lib/rex/post/meterpreter/ui/console/command_dispatcher/core.rb) states,

> "bgrun" => "Executes a meterpreter script as a background thread"

`Bgrun` executes a script in a background thread, however the `search` command can't be used with `bgrun`. The closest script I can find to the search command is [`search_dwld`](https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/blob/master/scripts/meterpreter/search_dwld.rb). `Search_dwld` works in a similar way to `search` and also downloads the files that have been found.

The usage for `search_dwld` is as follows:

> search_dwld -- recursively search for and download files matching a
>   given pattern
>
> USAGE: run search_dwld [base directory] [filter] [pattern]
>
> filter can be a defined pattern or 'free', in which case pattern must
>   be given
>
> Defined patterns:
>
> $filters.keys.sort.collect{|k|"\t#{k}"}.join("\n")
>
> Examples:   run search_dwld
>
> => recursively look for (MS|Open)Office in C:\
>
> run search_dwld %USERPROFILE% win9x
>
> => recursively look for *.PWL files in the user home directory
>
> run search_dwld E:\\ free '.(jpg|png|gif)$'
>
> => recursively look for pictures in the E: drive

You can use `search_dwld` with `bgrun` like this:

```
bgrun search_dwld
```

---

## File Collector

Another option is the [`file_collector`](https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/blob/master/scripts/meterpreter/file_collector.rb) script. As the link above states,

> Meterpreter Script for searching and downloading files that match a
>   specific pattern. First save files to a file, edit and use that same
>   file to download the choosen files.

`file_collector` is a three part process. First we create the file list, then we remove any files we don't want from the list, then we execute the download process. [Here is a guide](http://insidetrust.blogspot.co.uk/2010/10/post-exploitation-downloading-files.html) on how to use `file_collector`.

You can also use `file_collector` with `bgrun` as stated earlier with `search_dwld`:

```
bgrun file_collector
```

---

## Create script

Another alternative is to [make your own script](https://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/writing-meterpreter-scripts/) in Ruby which searches for files.

```
bgrun searchScript.rb
```

This could actually be a good solution as you can make the script fit your exact needs.

Comment: will this work with a post module? for instance run post/windows/gather/some-script if not how can I background a post module

Comment: As far as I am aware of, no. `bgrun` only works on Ruby scripts and can't execute post modules. I suppose you could run the post module, background the session and open a new session?

Comment: how would you do that? bcz `run` kinda blocks everything, unless there is a key combination like bash's ctrl+z

Comment: Yes, `ctrl+z` is the same as `background` command

Comment: that backgrounded the whole metasploit framework, not what I inteded to do. I meant I wanted to background only that script

Comment: Hmm, sorry, I'm not sure how to do it then